# div containing select not working after appending to form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form in which I have drop down menu to select a city. I want to add one more drop down to this form to select location in the selected city.  My form code looks as follows

```
<s:form  role="form" name = "signUpForm" onsubmit="return validateSignupForm()" action = "signUp" method="post" namespace="/" theme="simple">
    <div class ="form-group">
        <label for= "city">City</label>
            <select list="cityList" onchange="getLoad()" class="form-control selectpicker"  name="city" id="city"   data-live-search="true" data-size="5">
             <option value="NA">--select a city--</option>  
             <option value="A"> A</option>
             <option value ="B">B</option>
             <option value ="C">C</option>
             <option value ="D">D</option>
          </select> 
    </div>
    <div id="parentLocationDiv"></div>
 </s:form>
```

In addition to this I have created four separate div containing select options for location in city.

```
<div class="form-group" id="ALocation">
  <select id="alocation" name="alocation">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="BLocation">
  <select id="blocation" name="blocation">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Now to append these divs to the form I making use of the following javascript:

```
  function getLoad(){

     var ParentDiv  =   document.getElementById("parentLocationDiv"); 

     while(ParentDiv.hasChildNodes())
     {
         ParentDiv.removeChild(ParentDiv.childNodes[0]);
     }
            var cityName = document.getElementById("city").value;

                if(ParentDiv.hasChildNodes())
                {   while(ParentDiv.hasChildNodes())
                    {   
                        ParentDiv.removeChild(Parentdiv.childNodes[0]);

                    }
                }
                debugger;
                var clone = document.getElementById(cityName.concat("Location")).cloneNode(true);
                ParentDiv.appendChild(clone);
                ParentDiv.childNodes[0].style.display="block";
                var newdiv = ParentDiv.childNodes[0];
                newdiv.getElementsByTagName("select").name="location";
                newdiv.getElementsByTagName("select").id="location";

      }
```

Now  when I select a city corresponding  location drop down menu is visible in form but when I select any option it does not get selected.  Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Your codes seems to work except for throwing errors where there are no matching locations. You can fix it as follows:

```js
function getLoad() {

  var parentDiv = document.getElementById("parentLocationDiv");

  while (parentDiv.hasChildNodes()) {
    parentDiv.removeChild(parentDiv.childNodes[0]);
  }
  var cityName = document.getElementById("city").value || "";
  var target = document.getElementById(cityName.concat("Location"));
  if (!target)
    return;
  var clone = target.cloneNode(true);
  clone.getElementsByTagName("select").name = "location";
  clone.getElementsByTagName("select").id = "location";
  parentDiv.appendChild(clone);
  parentDiv.childNodes[0].style.display = "block";

}
```

```css
.holder {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form role="form" name="signUpForm" onsubmit="return validateSignupForm()" action="signUp" method="post" namespace="/" theme="simple">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="city">City</label>
    <select list="cityList" onchange="getLoad()" class="form-control selectpicker" name="city" id="city" data-live-search="true" data-size="5">
      <option value="NA">--select a city--</option>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="parentLocationDiv"></div>
</form>

<div class="form-group holder" id="ALocation">
  <select id="alocation" name="alocation">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group holder" id="BLocation">
  <select id="blocation" name="blocation">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```